Replace text in pdf using pdfbox
I need to find and replace some text in a pdf file in java.  I am using pdfbox.  I followed a few examples on SO none worked.  It seems every example is looking for operator tj or TJ but unfortunately, the pdf file I am working with does not have these operators.
If I open it on a pdf viewer, it is clearly a text (not graphic), I can select it.  If I load it with online editor such as https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor, I can select the text and replace it.
Here are the operators I have in the pdf:
q
BT
Td
ET
Q
q
cm
Do
Q
q
BT
Td
ET
Q
q
cm
Do
Q

So which operator should I be working on?
Thanks

Then likely in a form XObject, i.e. one or several (!) levels below. You should investigate the file with PDFDebugger.

"Here are the operators I have in the pdf:" - if those are all the operators you have in your whole PDF (and not merely in a single specific content stream), then there clearly is no text in it. "It seems every example is looking for operator tj or TJ" - that obviously is not enough as a quick look into the PDF specification would have shown. Look for Tj, ', ", and TJ.

It turns out the the compression.  with WriteDecodedDoc I was able to decode the pdf and found the Tj operator.
Thanks
